# Haskell avoiding double-wrapped maybes in functions that return maybes

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, option-type

I can see that there's a lot of questions asking about the Maybe type and composition here, but I'm quite stuck and reading these has my head hurting, if I'm being quite honest.

Here's my situation:

Say, for the sake of example, I have a function:

```
addm a b = Just (a + b)
```

How can I create a function `add :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int` using the `addm` function without using pattern matching to unwrap the `Maybe`s?

I have tried something like

```
add x y = (addm <$> x) <*> y
```

but this has a type of `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe (Maybe Int)`

I'd also like to avoid using anything outside of the standard library if possible.

Edit: In my specific case, I actually only needed a function `Maybe Int -> Int -> Maybe Int`
so I was able to use

```
add x y = x >>= addm y
```

which did the trick. I'm stil curious about the answer to the original question, though.

Comment: Aren't Applicative Functors what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe? I'm still very new to Haskell so I don't really understand how that applies to the situation. I think it would work fine if ```addm``` didn't return a Maybe itself.

Comment: It's been a long time since I was good with Haskell too, but maybe  this will help you : http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors .It's not the same, but maybe it will guide to to the right track

Comment: @GrayCat I'm pretty sure you need the `Monad` instance to do this, not just the Applicative methods

Comment: @GrayCat Good resource, thanks; but it hasn't really shown me anything I didn't see on Hoogle when looking up ```<*>``` and ```<$>```. I'm still pretty stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways to write this. All involve the fact that `Maybe` is a Monad.

Perhaps the easiest way to understand is to use the [join](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) function, which, for any Monad, removes the outermost level of nesting. Here it has type `Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a`, which is exactly what you are looking for, in combination with standard Applicative operators:

```
add ma mb = join $ addm <$> ma <*> mb
```

Or you can use `do` notation to write the computation in a more imperative style, with what look like variable assignments, in which the Monad takes care of propagating any `Nothing` values:

```
add ma mb = do
    a <- ma
    b <- mb
    addm a b
```

Or you could explicitly use the "bind" (`>>=`) operator, which is what the `do` block above desugars to (but I find this less explicit and understandable than the other two options):

```
add ma mb = ma >>= \a -> mb >>= \b -> addm a b
```

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for and thank you for approaching it from multiple angles as well! I'll be keeping this for reference!

Answer (score 5):

Stick a `join` on top.

```
Control.Monad.join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a -- combine two ms into one, this is why, as the meme goes, monads are monoids in the category of endofunctors

add x y = join $ addm <$> x <*> y
```

I would like to point out that writing `addm` like this (really, any function that always returns `Just`) is unnatural. You'd really just write `add x y = (+) <$> x <*> y` or just `add = liftA2 (+)`, but the general pattern of throwing `join` on top of an expression in applicative style is useful when you're dealing with actually interesting monadic code.

Comment: I very nearly pointed out in the comments that this definition of `addm` didn't need or want to use `Maybe` at all, but then I reflected that the OP said "for the sake of example" so I assume the real function is more complicated and involves some chance of yielding `Nothing`.

Comment: The addm function was just for the sake of example, I understand that writing a function that always returns a Just is unnatural, but thank you for the alternatives (and the solution to the question!)

Answer (score 3):

Use the <s>force</s> types, Luke!

Your `addm` has type `Int -> Int -> Maybe Int`. Your goal is to wrap it in a way that will give you a `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`. To do that, we need a function with type `(Int -> Int -> Maybe Int) -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`. If we [search for that type on Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(Int%20-%3E%20Int%20-%3E%20Maybe%20Int)%20-%3E%20Maybe%20Int%20-%3E%20Maybe%20Int%20-%3E%20Maybe%20Int), although there's no results in `base`, there are a few results in third-party libraries. [`liftJoin2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht/docs/Control-Monad-HT.html#v:liftJoin2) and [`bind2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/util/docs/Util.html#v:bind2) are equivalent, and both do exactly what you want. If you don't want to bring in a new dependency just for this, then check the source of those to see how they do it:

```
bind2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
bind2 f x y = liftA2 (,) x y >>= uncurry f
```

```
liftJoin2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
liftJoin2 f ma mb =
   join (liftM2 f ma mb)
```

(I modified `liftJoin2` here slightly to use only `base` methods directly, rather than `utility-ht`'s renamed wrappers.)